# Adding a RichTextEditor to PopUpManager seems to be very slow

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, flex3, adobe

As the topic states, using a Rich Text Editor with a PopUpManager makes typing slow. If you try it in Firefox/Mac, it is painful. Chrome/Mac is a little slower as well. Are there any known issues with the PopUpManager and performance that can be addressed easily?

Keep in mind, this is a Flex 3 application (can't update, unfortunately - business 'needs').

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure it's the RTE? Is there any other code that could be using a lot of CPU?  Post the code?

Comment: I haven't experience anything like this personally, can you provide some code as to how you're doing it? PopUps have some performance issues, mainly dealing with failure to garbage collect if you don't clean them up correctly. Are there any effects or anything like that you have going on?

Comment: http://cl.ly/1h1C3I0R3O250t0Y021y (Figured this was easier)

Comment: @Jonathan, what are some things to lookout for in terms of cleaning up properly?

Comment: Mainly just removing listeners or any references to the popup. I just tried your code BTW, and it worked fine... no performance impact. Do you per chance have the WMODE property set in your HTML template?? I'm on a windows machine.

Comment: If that code you pasted is the code that is running slow, it's not a flex / flash issue.  It runs fine here and many-a-projects (although, I generally hate PopUpManager).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has nothing to do with PopUpManager. Try using Flex/Flash builder to profile the app. See if there are any memory leaks.

Comment: I disagree. Even this is noticeably slower: http://cl.ly/1h1C3I0R3O250t0Y021y brand new application with nothing but popupmanager holding a RTE

Comment: Just tried out your code as in your screenshot (brand new app with just popup-manager holding RTE). Tried it on Windows, it was fast, as usual no slowdown seen. Will try the same on Mac , later this evening.